# Printing each character and adding on until sentence is finished?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I'm new to programming and I'm learning python. I'm confused about something. I wrote the code the same as my teacher did but with different variables and text. But the output for the "decoded message" was adding on characters each line until the sentence was finished. How do I fix this?

**Here is my code:**

```
message = "testing testing one two three"

encoded = []
decoded = " "

print("Encoded message:")
for n in message:
    encoded.append(ord(n))
    
for n in encoded:
    print(n),


print(" ")
print(“Decoded message:”)

for n in encoded:
    decoded = decoded + chr(n)
    print decoded
```

**And here is the output:**

```
Encoded message:
116 101 115 116 105 110 103 32 116 101 115 116 105 110 103 32 111 110 101 32 116 119 111 32 116 104 114 101 101  
Decoded message:

 t
 te
 tes
 test
 testi
 testin
 testing
 testing 
 testing t
 testing te
 testing tes
 testing test
 testing testi
 testing testin
 testing testing
 testing testing 
 testing testing o
 testing testing on
 testing testing one
 testing testing one 
 testing testing one t
 testing testing one tw
 testing testing one two
 testing testing one two 
 testing testing one two t
 testing testing one two th
 testing testing one two thr
 testing testing one two thre
 testing testing one two three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the tab:

```
for n in encoded:
    decoded = decoded + chr(n)
print(decoded)
```

Now `print(decoded)` is not a part of the `for` loop, therefore it will only print once.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that output because your `print decoded` line is indented into the `for` loop so every time it decodes a new character it will print the message again. 
so the code should be

```py
for n in encoded:
    decoded = decoded + chr(n)
print decoded
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `print` statement from the final `for loop`

However, your `decoded` will not be same as `message` since `decoded` is initialised with a `space` char and it remains as it is. You might have to fix it as well..

```
line4: decoded = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's *decoded*, as in, in the middle of the program, it was *encoded* with the Unicode character of each character. Perhaps this is easier to understand:

```
message = "testing testing one two three"

encoded = [str(ord(n)) for n in message]
decoded = [chr(int(n)) for n in encoded]

print("Encoded message:"," ".join(encoded))
print("Decoded message:","".join(decoded))
```

Output:

```
Encoded message: 116 101 115 116 105 110 103 32 116 101 115 116 105 110 103 32 111 110 101 32 116 119 111 32 116 104 114 101 101
Decoded message: testing testing one two three
```